# Java - Get name of button which triggerred mouseEvent

Tags: java, events, mouse, listeners

I have a Java program consisting of several class.

Now, I made the interface of the Java program in the class called **Application**.  I have defined several buttons there.

This is how I added the mouse listeners to the buttons in the **Application** class:

I have another class called **DrawingCanvas** which contains, amongst others, a number of mouse event handlers.  One of these event handlers is mousePressed.  Here is the code of mousePressed:

The problem with mousePressed is that it is not recognizing the button names such as "Button_Square", "Button_Rectangle" etc.  This is because these buttons have been declared in the **Application** class and NOT the **DrawingCanvas** class.

How can I get the name of the button which triggerred the mouse event please? Don't forget that the class in which the buttons have been declared is NOT the same as the class which implements the mouselisteners and mousemotionlisteners.  Thanks :)

Comment: Did you just create 8 DrawingCanvas's?

Comment: Erm..  I know that I may have some mistake in adding the mouse listeners and mouse motion listeners.  How do I add the mouselistener to the components?  All these listeners are in the DrawingCanvas class.

Comment: You should probably write a dispatcher class for each button which in turn calls the method on the DrawingCanvas class.

Comment: I solved that problem.  I created the DrawingCanvas once and am passing that instance in every call to mouselistener.

Comment: But how do I differentiate between the buttons pressed please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're going to create 8 different listeners, differentiate them with the JButton.

```
Button_Square.addMouseListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Square));
Button_Square.addMouseMotionListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Square));

Button_Rectangle.addMouseListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Rectangle));
Button_Rectangle.addMouseMotionListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Rectangle));

Button_Circle.addMouseListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Circle));
Button_Circle.addMouseMotionListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Circle));

Button_Triangle.addMouseListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Triangle));
Button_Triangle.addMouseMotionListener(new DrawingCanvas(Button_Triangle));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start, you can make a single DrawingCanvas and make that a field in your application class; here I'm going to call it `canvas`. Now, if all of your buttons do different things, you can give them all different MouseListeners:

```
Button_Rectangle.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
           if(!e.isControlDown())
           {
                 canvas.Shapes.add(new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY()));
           }
    }
    //handle other events, or don't directly implement MouseListener

});

Buuton_Circle.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
           if(!e.isControlDown())
           {
                 canvas.Shapes.add(new Circle(e.getX(), e.getY()));
           }
    }
    //handle other events, or don't directly implement MouseListener

});
```

so on...

Eliminating the need to determine the source by using different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can read text that you have set in the button.  If that text is unique, it will identify the button.  The following is logic I am using to identify and control JToggleButtons.

Note that once you have the Abstract button you might be able to do what you want with the button (e.g. get/set background colors) without parsing the text property.

Example:

```
void PrintEventProperties(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    AbstractButton EventSource = (AbstractButton)evt.getSource();
    System.out.println("Toggled on? " + EventSource.isSelected() );
    System.out.println("ID/text=" + EventSource.getText() );
    System.out.println("Color=" + EventSource.getBackground() );
}
```